# How to start gatsby using concurrently?

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby, package.json

I'm using `Gatsby` in conjuction with `Strapi` and I have separated this two project using the following structure:

```
backend <- contains Strapi
frontend <- contains Gatsby
package.json
```

Inside `package.json` I've installed `concurrently` because I would like to run `backend` and `frontend` at the same time:

```
 "scripts": {
    "backend_dev": "npm start --prefix backend strapi-develop",
    "frontend_dev": "npm start --prefix frontend develop",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend_dev\" \"npm run frontend_dev\""
  },
```

when I do: `npm run backend_dev` all is working fine, but when I try to start `Gatsby` I get:

> Unknown command develop

Seems like I cannot run a `Gatsby` site from the root folder, because if I do:

```
cd frontend
npm run develop
```

the site correctly start on the port `8000`

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

the fixed `package.json` is:

```
"backend_dev": "npm start --prefix backend strapi-develop",
"frontend_dev": "cd frontend && npm run develop",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend_dev\" \"npm run frontend_dev\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining commands with `&&` , this works in Windows also, check this related [npm ticket](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10958)

```
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend_dev\" \"cd frontend && npm run frontend_dev\""
```